# How to create an index on a date column

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that has a date column.  I have approx 800,000 rows in the table so I want to index.  The most common search is going to be:

```
  Select X,Y,Z from table where dateField='yyyy-mm-dd';
```

the date is in standard mysql yyyy-mm-dd format.

what type of index do i want to create?

```
CREATE INDEX 2013- ON customer (date(10));
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX 201 ON customer (date(10));
```

or am I way off?

I am new to indexing so any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an index on `dateField` and give it a simple name, such as the column name.

For example:

```
alter table your_table
  add index dateField (dateField);
```

Comment: I did this, and when i explain the select statement, possible rows drops from 890k to 573k.  Doesnt seem like much of an optimization.

Comment: I did see key_len is 14.  that seems awfully high for an index, should i reduce that?

Comment: What is the data type of your date field? If it's a `date` column then the key_len should be 3.

Comment: You knocked off a third of the rows - I'd say that's a decent optimization.

Comment: As for the "rows" in your explain, that will depend on the criteria you are using and the cardinality of the index. If the criteria matches 65% of the rows then the index would not save much time over a full table scan.

Comment: ok im starting to understand this. Thank you for your responses.